# Finding $\lim_{c \rightarrow 0} \iint_{R} \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}\,dA$ where $R$ is unit disk with square removed

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

For each $0 \leq c \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ define the following region

$$R=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \leq 1\} \setminus  ([-c,c] \times [-c,c])$$

Compute

$$\lim_{c \rightarrow 0} \iint_{R} \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}\,dA$$

Now, if we remove a circle instead of a square then using polar coordinates, we can easily find the answer which is $4\pi$. If we consider R as a type one or two region, then I do not know how to calculate the integral because it seems that we cannot make use of the polar coordinate anymore. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to compute the limit only and that is easy as you can (easily) argue that the limit is just the integral on the disc minus a point, which is just the integral on the disc since a point is irrelevant and polar coordinates work

Comment: How can we argue that? Can you elaborate a bit? I do not see which theorem you are using. @Conrad

Comment: Just take the function $f_c(x,y)=\frac{\chi_{R_c}}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}$ where $\chi_{R_c}$ is the characteristic function of the disc minus the square above with parameter $c$ and argue that the integral on the disc of $f_c$ converges to the integral on the disc of $f_0$ by say dominated (or monotone) convergence, while of course, the latter is just the integral on the punctured disc of $\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}$

Comment: I think you are using measure theory stuff. But it assumes we do not know measure theory, so it should have an easier solution. @Conrad

Comment: I think I understood your point.  You are meaning $f_c$'s are both dominated by and convergent to $f_0$? @Conrad

Comment: yes that's correct - this is just basic integration theory; note that I do not see an easy way to compute the integral on $R_c$ (maybe what would work directly is to estimate it between the integrals on the disc where you take out the circumscribed and inscribed disks to the square at least for small enough $c$ so those are inside the big disc and use polar coordinates then on the corresponding two annuluses and show that the two limits are equal to $4\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I_c$ be the integral of the function on the unit disk with $[-c,c]\times [-c,c]$ square removed. Let $J_c$ be the integral on the unit disk with the radius $c$ smaller disk centered on the origin removed.

As you’ve noticed using polar coordinates, $J_c=\int_c^1 2\pi r/r^{3/2}dr=[4\pi\sqrt{r}]^1_c=4\pi (1-\sqrt{c})$.

Since the function is positive, increasing the covered area will only increase the integral. Since the square in $I_c$ covers a circle of radius $c$ and lies within a circle of radius $2c$, we have that the region of $J_{2c}$ is within that of $I_c$ which is within that of $J_{c}$.

Thus,

$$ 4\pi(1-\sqrt{2c})=J_{2c}\leq I_c\leq J_c = 4\pi(1-\sqrt{c})$$

Applying the Squeeze Theorem gives that $\lim_{c \rightarrow 0^+} I_c=4\pi$ as desired.

Comment: Nice use of squeeze theorem, thanks! The last inequality is equality, right? @Eric

Comment: Yes. Updated that.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this directly (which to be fair is proper, since taking the limit along different shapes is akin to taking limits along different paths for multivariable limits, and you don't necessarily know ahead of time that the limit exists and therefore the limits along different paths equal each other), then consider the symmetries of the integral to rewrite it as

$$I_c = 8 \iint\limits_{R\:\cap\:x>y\:\cap\:y>0}\frac{dxdy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$

Transforming the equation of the line to polar coordinates, we obtain

$$c = x =r\cos\theta \implies r = c\sec\theta$$

giving us the bounds

$$I_c = 8 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{c\sec\theta}^1 r^{-\frac{1}{2}}\:dr\:d\theta = 4\pi-16\sqrt{c}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sqrt{\sec\theta}\:d\theta$$

From here, taking the limit requires not much further justification to say
$$\lim_{c\to0}I_c = \boxed{4\pi}$$

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ not $r$

Comment: @Eric yes you're right, thanks for finding that! I have fixed it.